# Describing holomorph of dihedral group

Tags: group-theory, book-recommendation, dihedral-groups, holomorph

Are there any articles or books, where ${\rm Hol}(D_{2n}$) ($D_{2n}$ is dihedral group of order $2n$), is described?Semidirect product seems like very hard thing to compute, but I'm interested whether this holomorph is embedded in something nice.

Comment: You can compute semidirect products in GAP.

Comment: For any group $G$ the holomorph of $G$ embeds in ${\rm Sym}(|G|)$.

Answer (score 3):

So the holomorph of a group (you may know) is the semi-direct product $$\rm hol(G):=G\rtimes \rm Aut (G),$$ where it's to be understood that we have the identity homomorphism $\varphi: \rm Aut(G)\to\rm Aut(G).$

Thus it's not abelian.

In the case of $D_{2n},$ we have that $$\rm Aut(D_{2n})\cong \rm hol(\Bbb Z_n).$$

Thus we get $$\rm hol(D_{2n})\cong \rm D_{2n}\rtimes \rm hol(\Bbb Z_n).$$

But, $$\rm hol(\Bbb Z_n)\cong \Bbb Z_n\rtimes \Bbb Z_n^×.$$

So, we get $$D_{2n}\rtimes (\Bbb Z_n\rtimes \Bbb Z_n^×).$$

Thus we get that the order is $$2n^2\varphi (n)$$ (Euler's totient).

---

So, it's embedded in $S_{2n^2\varphi (n)},$ by Cayley's theorem.

But better can be done. Thanks to @Derek Holt for pointing out that the holomorph naturally embedds in $S_{\lvert G\rvert},$ or $S_{2n}$ in this case.

Comment: In fact ${\rm hol}(G)$ embeds naturally in ${\rm Sym}(|G|)$ for all groups $G$, so ${\rm hol}(D_{2n})$ embeds in ${\rm Sym}(2n)$.

Comment: That's interesting.   I need to read more about it.  Maybe about the permutation description.   @DerekHolt

Comment: You could think of it as the permutation representation on the cosets of the subgroup ${\rm Aut}(G)$. Since ${\rm Aut}(G)$ acts faithfully on $G$, it is a core-free subgroup, so this permutation representation is faithful. Alternatively, $G$ acts on $G$ by right/left multiplication as in Cayley's Theorem, and ${\rm Aut}(G)$ acts on $G$ just as it does: the subgroup of ${\rm Sym}(G)$ generated by these actions is the holomorph.