# Must a group of order $20$ have an element of order $10$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I'm trying to show that if $G$ is a group of order $20$, then it will have an element of order $10$.

Considering the Sylow $5$-subgroups, we have $n_5 \equiv 1 \mod 5$ and $n_5 | 4$, so $n_5=1$ and so we have one cyclic subgroup of order $5$ and thus $4$ elements of order $5$.

Similarly, $n_2 \equiv 1 \mod 2$ and $n_2|5$ so $n_2=1$ or $5$. If we have $n_2 = 5$ then we can have at most $5 \cdot 3 = 15$ elements of order $2$ in the group, which would occur if the Sylow $2$-subgroups are disjoint copies of $C_2 \times C_2$.

In this case, alongside the identity, we have accounted for all $1+4+15=20$ elements and we don't have an element of order $10$. Otherwise we have elements of order $10$ and $20$ and we are done.

So, I am wondering how (if?) we can rule out this one particular case, or if there is a better method for showing that there must be an element of order $10$.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Isn't that a group of order $2^{10} = 1024$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find four groups of order 20 not isomorphic to each other.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/577917/find-four-groups-of-order-20-not-isomorphic-to-each-other)

Comment: Seems that $C5:C4$ is a counterexample.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I haven't encountered the classification of groups of order 20, in particular semidirect products and Galois groups - is it possible that there's a way to do this in a more elementary way?

Comment: @Peter I'm not sure if I understand this notation, can you explan what you mean by $C_5 : C_4$? Thanks!

Comment: Robin, no need to know the Galois group of $x^5-2$. It is the subgroup of $S_5$ generated by $(12345)$ and $(1243)$, so you can compute explicitly the order of elements!

Comment: @AnneBauval It possibly does but what I see in those answers is beyond what I've learned so far, is there a more elementary way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I see, thank you. I see that since $S_5$ does not have an element of order 10, neither does this.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Everything is clear, thanks. If you want to write up an answer containing this then I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Frobenius group of order $20$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1072830/galois-group-of-the-splitting-field-of-the-polynomial-x5-2-over-mathbb-q?noredirect=1&lq=1), which arises as the Galois group of $X^5-2$ over $\Bbb Q$, is a subgroup of $S_5$, i.e.,
generated by $(12345)$ and $(1243)$. It is isomorphic to the semidirect product $C_5\rtimes C_4$. Since $S_5$ has no element of order $10$, it has no element of order $10$ either.

However, since all groups of order $20$ are supersolvable, they satisfy the converse of Lagrange: since $10$ divides $20$, there is a subgroup of order $10$ in all cases. For CLT-groups (converse Lagrange groups) see here:

[Complete classification of the groups for which converse of Lagrange's Theorem holds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2144077/complete-classification-of-the-groups-for-which-converse-of-lagranges-theorem-h)

Answer (score 4):

Consider the holomorph $\rm hol(C_5)=C_5\rtimes \rm Aut(C_5)$.  Thus it embeds in $S_5,$ which has no element of order $10.$

The is also the Frobenius group,  or second Suzuki group $\rm Sz(2).$  It's the only counterexample.

Comment: How do you know that it embeds into $S_5$?

Comment: That's a general fact about the holomorph.   @Devo. $\rm hol(G)$ happens to embed in $S_{\lvert G\rvert}.$

Comment: See Derek Holt's two comments here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4628060/1070376 @Devo

Answer (score -1):

If $G$ is abelian, then the answer is yes, because said $x$ and $y$ two elements of order $2$ and $5$ respectively (which both exist by Cauchy's theorem), the product $xy$ has order $10$. So, to look for possible counterexamples, we have to turn our attention to nonabelian groups, where semidirect products assist ($D_{10}$ is not a candidate, though, because by definition it has an element of order $10$). Now, $C_5$ acts only trivially by automorphisms on both $C_4$ and $C_2\times C_2$ (see *e.g.* [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4116190/1092170)), a situation which leads to direct products of abelian groups, and hence abelian in turn. Thereofore, we are left to look for some truly semidirect product $(C_2\times C_2)\ltimes C_5$ or $C_4\ltimes C_5$. But the former would be equivalent to a homomorphism $\varphi\colon C_2\times C_2\to C_4$, which must be trivial as well, because a generator of $C_4$ can not be the image of elements of order $2$. So we are left to look at $C_4\ltimes C_5$ for a possible group without elements of order $10$, and both the other answers confirm that this is indeed the case.

Comment: For the downvoter: can you justify otherwise why to address *ex nihilo* abruptly $C_4\ltimes C_5$ as candidate? Looks like magics otherwise.